# VS Code with es6

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am getting the linting error in my code `'import' is only available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6').`

Everything es6 related is throwing an error. Not sure what I have to configure to get it to work.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

Add a file named `.jshintrc` to your project and inside this file type this:

```
{
    "esversion": 6
}
```

As you can see it here:

[image]

The full documentation of `jshint` options are found here: http://jshint.com/docs/options

Comment: http://jshint.com/docs/options/#esversion for those looking for the documentation.

Comment: This should be added automatically.

Comment: seems like at times you need to add this line  "moz": true

Comment: This didn't work for me (vscode version 1.37.1, OS X).

Go to the extension preferences --> select Edit in settings.json
To the JSON add:

`"jshint.options": { "esversion": 6 }`

Don't forget the comma on the previous line!

Comment: The only place to add this is in `~/settings.json` in my experience. Project level settings won't affect it. It is absurd this isn't the default. It is really hard to find out how to fix this and in the meantime the user experience with javascript in VS Code is hostile. Super annoying. It should support ES6+ by default. Why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 132):

**Edit: I've added a way to enable es6 if you use ESLint instead of JSHint as well as updating the screenshots since VSCode has changed since my original answer.**

## JSHint Method:

If you are using JSHint, you can add the following to your settings:

```
"jshint.options":{
    "esversion":6
}
```

## ESLint Method:

If you are using ESLint, you can add the following to your settings:

```
"eslint.options": {
    "env":{
        "es6":true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6 // or 7,8,9
    }
}
```

[ESLint Configuration Documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring)

## How to update the settings

0. Neither JSHint or ESLint are enabled in a fresh version of VS Code, so you'll need to install the extension(s) by going to extensions and then searching for your preferred linter.
1. In VS Code, head to `settings`

[image: VS Code Settings]

2. When the settings display you'll see the settings sections:

[image: User and Workspace Settings Tabs]

Note that there are two sections where you can customize your settings, ***User Settings*** and ***Workspace Settings***

**User Settings** Is where you should apply any global settings you will want for any project you will ever work on.

**Workspace Settings** Is where you can make settings changes that should only be applied to your current project.

In my case, since I know that only some of my projects can use ES6, I need to have the error hinting to warn me if I'm using ES6 my non-ES6 projects...so I set this only to my **Workspace Settings**

But, if you know that anything you code in VS Code is going to be an ES6, project, then save a step, and add it to your **user settings**.

3. Click on either User/Workspace depending on your preference. Search for JSHint or ESLint (whichever you use). Click on any of the *Edit in settings.json* links, it doesn't matter which one.

[image: Edit in settings.json]

4. Add the pertinent settings depending on whether you use JSHint or ESLint:

**JSHint**

[image: Adding the JSHint Setting]

**ESLint**

[image: Adding the ESLint Setting]

Comment: This was a great answer and +1 for not having to create an additional file within project directories...Screenshots also very helpful, thank you so much!

Comment: Also this is better as can be done automatically for new projects, instead of creating new files, or just kept within a single workspace.

Comment: Doesn't work for me for some reason. I tried it in both user and workspace settings

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed explanation, it was very helpful indeed.

Comment: Thank you. Following code worked for me.
`"jshint.options":{
    "esversion":6
}
`

Answer (score 27):

You can add `"esversion": 6` to `"jshint.options"` in the user settings.

```
{
  "jshint.options": {
    "esversion": 6
  }
}
```

Comment: mine has another entry  `"jshint.config": "",` just add `"jshint.options": {
    "esversion": 6
  }` afterwards do not confuse.

Answer (score 13):

Just to round out the excellent suggestions already submitted, you can also set this on a file by file basis by added this escaped line (and similar for other jshint settings) to the top of your file.

```
// jshint esversion:6
```

Actually you can add it anywhere, but it only effects subsequent code, allowing you to flip settings on and off if you're desperate to do something weird.

Answer (score 3):

Add the next hint before your code:

```
/* jshint esversion: 6 */
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G50oa.png)

Comment: simplest to do in a mixed development environment

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you do the above configurations with the json but also remove/disable the `jshint` extension for workspace if you're using `eslint` and vice versa.,

Answer (score -1):

Disable your jshint extension like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYnM2.png]