# Typescript: How to modify tsconfig to support class (I'm not talking about module)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have this tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "outFile": "index.js"
  }
}
```

When I compile I have an error when creating  a class: 
Use esversion: es6

Where do I add this line ? Is it really in tsconfig ?

Answer (score 1):

> You write TS sources using ES6 modules, however as of January 2016 no browser natively supports this module system. So you may want to transpile ES6 modules into a different module system: CommonJS, AMD, SystemJS. This can be done using module option. There are build-time or run-time transpilers that transpile the ES6 module system into one of the module systems supported by a build system (Webpack) or a module loader (SystemJS). If not specified, the module defaults to ES6 if target is ES6, or CommonJS otherwise. I prefer to set target to CommonJS explicitly:

Probably you should add `module` property.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "CommonJS" // for exapmle
   }
}
```

Also you should add `lib`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    }
}
```

For more details: https://indepth.dev/configuring-typescript-compiler/

Comment: are you sure it answer my question about class I'm not talking about module ?

Comment: I am talking about module resolution. JavaScript classes, introduced in ECMAScript 2015, are primarily syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. So you need to convert es2015 syntax to be understandable for browsers ( if you developed for browsers of course)

Comment: Set target to ‘es6’. This will let the TypeScript compiler generate ECMAScript 6 code, which is almost line-for-line the same as TypeScript code. Set module to ‘commonjs’ so your TypeScript modules work just like node’s modules and npm packages. If you develop for the browser, it’s probably better to set it to ‘amd’ (for use with libraries like require.js). https://tvcutsem.github.io/2016/01/my-ES6-development-setup     https://medium.com/@tommedema/typescript-confusion-tsconfig-json-module-moduleresolution-target-lib-explained-65db2c44b491

Comment: Or maybe you have problem with linter? You should provide more details. If you have problem with linter, take a look please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318895/vs-code-with-es6

Comment: must be linter though I don't understand why I need linter but thanks will look at it.