# Downloaded Javascript: Vscode does not recognise 'let' and 'const'

Tags: visual-studio-code, ecmascript-6

I am new to JS.
I installed a free *Lynda* course on *Functional Javascript for ES6*.
This required installing *npm* and *Node*, which appear to be OK.

Now in vscode, when I type the first line of a .js file, it does not recognise `const` or `let`.
It accepts `var` but then doesn't recognise the `=>` element.
The line I typed is `` const sayHello = name => console.log(`Hello ${name}`); ``
I get yellow wavy lines under `const` and `=>` and `` `H ``.
I have searched vscode Settings but cannot find anything relevant.
This has happened before, so it's not a simple mistake on my part, as far as I can see.

No point doing the course if I'm stuck in ES5. How do I convert to ES6? I am running a Mac with Catalina 10.15.7.
Can anyone help?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Aaz.png)

Comment: The line I typed is missing backticks before the H in Hello and after {name}. They do not show up for some reason.

Comment: What messages do you see when you hover over the yellow lines?  Have you checked the settings for JSHint or ESLint?  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48848631/5365001

Comment: For the missing backticks - see this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82722/907170

Comment: @LHM, There are no message when I hove over. I have temporarily solved this instance of the problem by writing a file .jshintrc as described in [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48848631/5365001), and currently trying to absorb the intricacies of finding a global solution. Question: should I be using EsLint or JsHint or both? Not sure what they do apart from indicated format problems etc. My needs are not great, js is a retirement hobby. Is using both actually overkill? Would appreciate .advice

Comment: @LHM I don't want to start an edit war or argue with you, but why do you think the post is clearer after your edit?

Comment: @FZs, you are correct - the edits that ended up submitted were not very substantive (and in the case of the line of code and screenshot - it is less clear now).  I had made more substantive edits, but the edit queue was full at the time.  I left the tab open, and in the meantime you made most of the edits that I was planning.  I didn't notice this, however, and simply submitted my previously made edits when I found the open tab waiting with the old edits.  This reverted the good formatting edits that you had made. My apologies that I wasn't more careful.

Comment: @LHM No problem, I just wanted to understand that (you have essentially reverted the changes I made and wanted to know why)...

Comment: Yes - very sorry about that - I hope you will submit your edits again as they definitely made the question easier to read.